# student's grade average and subject's grade average calculator in python

Tags: python

i am making a calculator in python which gives me students grade average and also subject grade average.
below is a picture of how i need my inputs and how my output should look.

I am trying to use nested lists and functions.I tried this.

Comment: I think it is more practical to put all grades in an excel or csv file, the columns or rows of which can be read into python. To compute an average, look up numpy mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a `while` loop and Pandas

```
import pandas

list_marks = {}

subjects = int(input("Number of subjects: "))

while(True):
    name = input("Name of student (leave empty if finished): ")
    if not name:
        break

    scores = []
    for i in range(1, subjects + 1):
        scores.append(int(input("Subject %d: " % i)))

    list_marks[name] = scores

scores = pandas.DataFrame(list_marks)
print(scores)
#     student1  student2  student3
# 0       100        90        80
# 1       100        90        60
print(scores.mean(axis=0))
# student1    100.0
# student2     90.0
# student3     70.0
# dtype: float64
print(scores.mean(axis=1))
# 0    90.000000
# 1    83.333333
# dtype: float64
```

or using NumPy:

```
import numpy

scoresarray = numpy.array(list(list_marks.values()))
print(numpy.mean(scoresarray, axis=0))
# [ 90.          83.33333333]
print(numpy.mean(scoresarray, axis=1))
# [ 100.   90.   70.]
```

Comment: Nils, sir can you please post your previous answer that you posted in the beginning.

Comment: I have added both Pandas and NumPy solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  def calc(student_count):
        list_marks = []
        for i in range(int(student_count)):
            student_name = input("name of student?")
            sub1_score = input("Score of subject 1?")
            sub2_score = input("Score of subject 2?")
            average = (int(sub1_score) + int(sub2_score))/2
            list_marks.append([student_name,sub1_score,sub2_score,average])
        print (list_marks)
        return list_marks                    


    no_of_students = input("How many students?")
    #no_of_subjects = input("How many subjects?")
    calc(no_of_students)
```

This will produce the output you want for two subjects.

If you have many subjects, sum them and divide by their count

Comment: Thanks, in your code we have to change input to raw_input when asking 'name_of_student'. any ideas how to print average too?

Comment: @SRingne I added it to the code, didn't test it but it should work fine

Comment: the no. of subjects are also dynamic, not just 2